# How to advance a plot whose conflict is the social quirks of the unbalanced protagonist?

Tags: planning, writers-block

I am a beginning creative writer seeking advice.

I am not asking for people to write my story for me; I have a story idea where the conflict revolves around the unbalanced protagonist's social troubles (social anxiety, awkwardness, foreigner, and prejudice.)

I find myself lost in how to drive a plot forward with just social challenges. I have conlangs and conworlds in mind, but I'm not sure how to utilize those. Maybe I'm feeling creative-block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Having a flawed protagonist is a good start.

To advance a story, in the typical fashion, is to have your protagonist confronted by obstacles (conflict) that they must learn to overcome.

If your story revolves around the protagonist becoming less flawed (goal) -- less prejudiced, more at ease in their society, etc.-- then you might create situations that would difficult for your protagonist to handle; then, through a process of trial and error, they learn about themselves and change.  But, personal change happens from desire (motivation). So they have to have some compelling reason to change. IF you did that, it would be a pretty normal story.

Or you can give them some goal and a reason to want to achieve that goal, and chose their flaws so that make it even harder to achieve their goal. Like, they want to be elected to office so they can fix some bad law, but they are goofy and awkward so they are really bad at public speaking.  They may not be able to change themselves, some of our flaws are just who we are. But, they can learn to cope with their flaws and overcome them.  They might still be goofy and awkward, but they pretend to be something else in public.

The idea is to put your character in a situation with a goal and a motivation and put something in the way of achieving that goal. Then, write the story.  If you that you'll find you have as interesting a story as you are capable of writing.